# Include 404 Error Page

Tags: php, iis, iis-8

I'm trying to return the default 404 error page in IIS-8. I'm using this code:

```
// Return 404 in case no product was found
if($product_index == -1) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    exit;
}
```

This code responds with a 404-error, but the page is just blank.
Is there a way to include the default 404 error page using PHP?

Comment: You can add a `location` to go to  the 404 page : `header('Location:404.html');`

Comment: Yes, that could work, but I want to keep the user on the same page (instead of redirecting, I would use include). How do I obtain the 404 error page-file path?

Comment: Its not clear what are you saying? If the user opens the page that does not exists at all then he must be send to 404 page only.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add header again for redirecting to 404 page like below:

```
// Return 404 in case no product was found
if($product_index == -1) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    header("Location: http://yoursite/404.php");
    exit;
}
```

If you still get trouble due to IIS-8, then you can follow [Custom 404 error page not working on IIS 8.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31227884/custom-404-error-page-not-working-on-iis-8-5)