# Handle "A potentially dangerous Request" in IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-10

I have hosted an MVC web application in my local system. When my application was tested using a VAPT tool by external Auditors, they discovered an error when they accessed the application using the following URL : https://10.25.71.117/uncpath/alert("123"). The error is:" A potentially dangerous Request. Path value was detected from the client (<)." Here my application is not uncpath. As my application itself is called, I want to handle the error through IIS server. For that I need to know the Error status code for this kind of requests and handle it using a custom error. Thanks in advance for help! [Unhandled Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVYQq.png)

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want answered, but the status code for this is 400

Comment: @FLeX I want to how to configure the IIS to handle this error instead of showing the yellow page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like Custom error pages:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httperrors/
- [Custom 404 error page not working on IIS 8.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31227884/custom-404-error-page-not-working-on-iis-8-5)

If you try but fail to implement, feel free to post your attempt(s) here and their results.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help. I Configured the Custom Error Page in the IIS server for Default Web Site under .NET Error pages. Status : 400 and Absolute URL: %SystemDrive%\inetpub\custerr\en-US\400.htm . Then added the file 400.htm in the specified Directory.

Comment: You are welcome! If this was helpful and was the answer for you, feel free to mark my response as the answer ;)