# Coldfusion - Redirect website if it hits /folder/index.cfm?

Tags: redirect, coldfusion

Very new to Coldfusion, but not to web development so hopefully this is an easy question.

We recently changed a link on our website that took us to `/folder/index.cfm`. I want to make sure that when someone types `www.ourwebsite.com/folder` that it doesn't take them to `/folder/index.cfm` and instead to redirect them to another website.

Any pointers?

Comment: This is probably more of a job for your web.config file (or equivalent) - but if you need to get to get it done in ColdFusion, dump out your CGI scope on that `index` page. It'll show you all the URL variables you're dealing with. After that, a quick check with an if-statement and a `<cflocation>` will solve the issue.

Comment: All popular webservers (nginx, IIS, Apache httpd) offer redirects based on patterns. You should edit your question/add corresponding tag, so we can help you with the "how to". The "easiest" solution though, is using [<cflocation>](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-j-l/cflocation.html) on your `/folder/index.cfm`, as already described by James.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least three ways it to do this.

1. Don't even bother with ColdFusion. Have your web server do the redirect. You are going to need to know if it Apache or IIS or whatever. You can then search for how that web server does it.

This might help you with some of that: [Custom 404 error page not working on IIS 8.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31227884/custom-404-error-page-not-working-on-iis-8-5/33584285)

2. You can make a file at `/folder/index.cfm` and have a file that has

OR with cfscript

```
 <cfscript>
   location("newpage.cfm", false, 301) 
 </cfscript>
```

Note the addtoken and statuscode are optional. Add token helps because almost no CF website uses this kind of token. The status code helps because tells the browser that this is a permanent move.

3. You could intercept the request in `application.cfc` . In fact, in some systems all requested are checked for validity in `application.cfc`. You might still need a blank page at the target, but at least some ColdFusion is processed

---

Of all the options, 1 is my favorite, because there really isn't a lot that can be done with requests to missing pages. And the list of potential missing pages is unlimited.

Comment: Tag based and only a single line: `<cflocation url="http://example.org" statusCode="301" addToken="false">` (older verisons of ACF require a semicolon at the end of the line in your cfscript variant btw.)

Comment: isn't adding rule in web.config better option